# How to send array through nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodemailer

```
var datas = [
  { date: 'Fri 09, Apr', price: 239, currency: 'i' },
  { date: 'Fri 09, Apr', price: null, currency: null },
  { date: 'Fri 09, Apr', price: null, currency: null },
  { date: 'Mon 12, Apr', price: 239, currency: 'i' },
  { date: 'Mon 12, Apr', price: null, currency: null },
  { date: 'Wed 14, Apr', price: 339, currency: 'i' },
  { date: 'Wed 14, Apr', price: null, currency: null }
]

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: "gmail",
            auth: {
              user: 'dummy@gmail.com', 
              pass: 'dummy'
            }
          });
         let mailOptions = {
           from: 'dummy@gmail.com',
           to: 'dummy@gmail.com',
           subject: 'Email subject',
           text: datas // ( not working this way)
         };
          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, data){
            if (err) {
              console.log('Error occurs');
            } else { console.log('Email sent!');}
          });


        }
    }
```

Hi, i searched after this, but i did not found any working solution. How could i send this variable, containing an array, in a message? with nodemailer? How could i parse it to a html format or anything?

Comment: if you want it as JSON - use JSON.stringify

Comment: Thank you. it works, now the only one i have to solve is giving that string some look